# Exclude a test method "A" and include Test method "B" which depends on "A"

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng

I have got individual testng xml files to run different test class. Now I have got a testclass named "class1" which has got 3 methods(A, B and C) inside. In "Class1", B method depends on "A", always run=false, method C depends on B and always run = false.

Now "Class2" extends "Class1". I would like to run only methods A and C, skipping B. So, I wrote class2XML like

```
   {<classes>
        <class name="class2">
            <methods>
                <include name="A" />
                <exclude name="B" />
                <include name="C" />
            </methods>
        </class>

    </classes>}
```

I am using maven to run my tests, testng is not allowing me to run the test methods like this. I am getting org.testng.DependencyMap.getMethodDependingOn error all the time. Wondering, is there any way I can exclude only method B. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. alwaysrun is by default false.  So you need not explicity set it
2. If you want testcases to run even if their dependencies are not there, then you would need to add ignoreMissingDependencies = true to your @Test

However, the functionality was not working till late and only recently (in 6.9-SNAPSHOT) has been fixed.  So, if you would need it, you need to download the latest code, build it and use that jar.